# Python: Getting values from the list

Tags: python

I am retriving data from psql database and I get my values like below:

```
list = [('value1','value2')]
```

I want to store the values in two different variables var1 and var2 like below:

```
var1 = 'value1'
var2 = 'value2'
```

How exactly can I do this?

I tried to do this like below:

```
var1 = list[0][0]
var2 = list[0][1]
print var1 (gives me the output value1 and not 'value1')
print var2 (gives me the output value2 and not 'value2')
```

Comment: In shell all string will output without quotes, so all is fine...

Comment: `print(type(var1))` if it says string you're good to go.

Comment: You want quotes displayed around the values? `print "'" + var1 + "'"`

Comment: Well, I'm trying to run it in my web browser (Python tornado framework used with psql backend) by retrieving id and password from database, when it goes with quotes password verification happens and it is not happening without quotes.

Comment: You should show that code then.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add actual quotes to your string you can use:

```
v1, v2 = map(lambda x: "'{}'".format(x), alist[0])
```

And please don't use reserved keyword `list` to name your variable.